# overrule overflow:hidden

Tags: css, position, overflow

it is the opposite of this [Keeping overflow:hidden really hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464803/keeping-overflowhidden-really-hidden) because i need that a child element gets visible although its out of the parent element.

it is a slideshow:
the parent-div (for example 500x250px) has width, height, position:relative (needs this) and left: 15px, overflow:hidden
there are some child-divs with the images (+text) included and a prev/next-div. 
the prev/next div have left resp. right -15px. looks quite cool on screen...

but because of the overflow:hidden (plus position:relative) from the parent the half of prev/next-div isn't visible 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/lookactually.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/shouldlook.png/

Comment: So you need overflow:hidden for certain childs and for others overlow:auto?

Comment: Please make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EsPHG/
i need that the slides are position absolute because they scroll out on the left side. i use jQuery with the cycle plugin.

i know there is the possibility to make <div id="slideshowholder"> with the same properties like #slideshow and put the prev/next-divs there. like:
<div id="slideshowholder>
<div id="slideshow>......</div>
<div id="prev></div>
<div id="next"></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

A child of an overflow:hidden element can never be visible outside it's parents' box(these are the rules)

to get around this you could place the navigation outside the overflow:hidden element or you could just increase the height of the parent div to accommodate the navigation.

Comment: thank you, i thought there could be any rule, that make this possible.

i will now make a div outside where i put the #prev/#next divs in.